# passing *this to template function with boost::serialization code makes error

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference, boost-serialization

I have a free template function that loads from a text file:

```
// free template function
template<class U>
bool Main_Load(U& dataset, const std::string path) {
    // Create an input archive
    std::ifstream ifs(path);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive archive_text(ifs);

    // Load data
    archive_text & dataset;
}
...
// in main()
Dataset1 dataset_restored;
Main_Load(dataset_restored, filename); // <--- OK
```

But I get an error "what():  input stream error" when I call this template function from a member function:

```
class Dataset1 {
...
virtual auto LoadDataset(AUX::DATA::SerializationType serialisation_type=AUX::DATA::SerializationType::Xml) -> bool {
    Main_Load(*this, GetPath()); // <--- ERROR
};
};
...
// in main()
Dataset1 dataset_restored;
dataset_restored.LoadDataset(AUX::DATA::SerializationType::Text);
```

Why can I pass dataset_restored but not *this of the same object? I suppose there is something wrong with *this in conjunction with:

```
archive_text & dataset;
```

**EDIT**
I have answered my own question. See below.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug in my code.

The bug was in line 488 of my code (see below for a link):

```
// Load/Save
virtual auto LoadDataset(AUX::DATA::SerializationType serialisation_type=AUX::DATA::SerializationType::Xml) -> bool {
    return AUX::DATA::Load(*this, GetPath(), serialisation_type);
    //return Main_Load(*this, GetPath());
};
virtual auto SaveDataset(AUX::DATA::SerializationType serialisation_type=AUX::DATA::SerializationType::Xml) const -> bool {
    return AUX::DATA::Save(*this, GetPath(), serialisation_type); // the ERROR was here mit 'this' passed and not '*this' so it saved but the load method (four lines up) did not work in conjunction with boost::serialization
    //return Main_Save(*this, GetPath());
};
```

It took me three days of sweating and three nights of crying to make an example code in boost::serialization that I can take for my future work. The documentation is horrible so I want to share the code with the public.

Here is the full example for boost::serialiazation with inheritance, == in all data classes for testing of equality and with two test cases in main():

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e241bda2210e3d02

It can save and load in binary, text and xml (change first line in main()).

Additionaly it has an optional manager that stores multiple datasets in a map and stores/loads them into/from seperate files all at once (see the second use case in main()).

In some members you can see alternative code that should work too for text and binary format:

```
template <class T>
void Dataset1::save_impl_text_binary(T& archive, const unsigned int version) const {
    archive & boost::serialization::base_object<Dataset0>(*this);
    archive & m_a1_;
    archive & m_b1_;
/*  archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Dataset0);
    archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_a1_);
    archive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_b1_); */
}
```